# How to fill dropdown list form database table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

How do I fill Drop Down List from Database Table using ajax call to controller? I have tried this.

AJAX Call

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetDropDown",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            alert("success");
            $.each(r.d, function () {
                alert("error");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Controller Code:

```
public static Shelf<ShelfItems> GetDropDown()
        {
            string query = "SELECT StoreID";
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    List<ListItem> customers = new List<ListItem>();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            customers.Add(new ListItem
                            {
                                Value = sdr["CustomerId"].ToString(),
                                Text = sdr["Name"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();

                }
            }
             return customers;
        }
```

Model :

```
   public class Shelf
        {
            public string StoreID { get; set; }
            public string ShelfName { get; set; }
            public string MinTemperature { get; set; }
            public string MaxTemperature { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: is your ajax call triggering your method..??

Comment: In you ajax Call your URL is Wrong You should give it as ControllerName/Method ie., YourControllerName/GetDropDown

Comment: You are specifying the ajax call to be "POST" while you are getting the data. Change it to "GET" and specify the controller name in the URL. Also remove the attribute data and dataType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct your select query as

```
 string query = "SELECT CustomerId,Name From yourTableName";
```

Answer (score 1):

use this: In Html:

```
      $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("AllCustomer", "Customers")',
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify(),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#customers').empty().append('<option value="">---Select---</option>');
                            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                                $('#customers').append($('<option />', {
                                    value: value.Id,
                                    text: value.Name
                                }));
                            });
                        },
                    });
```

in action:

```
public ActionResult AllCustomer()
{
  return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now edit on you own way

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/ControllerName/ActionName',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#customers').empty().append('<option value="">--Select---</option>');
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#customers').append($('<option />', {
                    text: value.StoreID
                }));
            });
        },
    });
```

In Controller

```
    public virtual JsonResult GetDropDown()
    {
        string query = "SELECT StoreID";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        List<ListItem> customers = new List<ListItem>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        customers.Add(new ListItem
                        {
                            Value = sdr["CustomerId"].ToString(),
                            Text = sdr["Name"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();

            }
        }
        return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```